# Android message “Allow <app name> to access <device-name>? (responded OK) continually repeating while app is in use over USB

Tags: android, notifications, usb, message

We have an ultrasound scanner that connects to our app on Android devices via USB or a built-in WiFi mini-router.

When connected over USB, one of our customers randomly gets the message “Allow  to access ? [set to OK).  Also, an option to “Always open  when  is connected?” (shouldn’t be related, but tried both on and off).  Brand new Samsung Galaxy Android S8 Ultra Tablet.

Unable to duplicate in our offices, even when using the same model ultrasound and same model tablet.  As expected, the message only appears on a new Android or after a factory reset.  It also runs fine at numerous other customer locations.

Tried (1) Android setting “Allow Notifications” off and on, (2) “Notification Categories” indicates “This app hasn’t sent you any notifications.” (3) WiFi and Bluetooth both off and on, (5) both Android and the app are current, (4) neither Samsung nor Google has had any other suggestions,

Not sure if/how this might factor in.  When connecting via the built-in WiFi, any Android or iOS device quickly drops the signal while inside the building, but runs fine in the parking lot or elsewhere.  Unfortunately, too many other companies in the building to start shutting off routers, and where this occurred at other locations, changing the WiFi channel in the app, turning off other routers, or resorting to the USB cable always solved it.

Any suggestions much appreciated.  Thanks, David

Comment: Have you considered that either the scanner or the android device may be faulty?  Have you tried switching one of them out? The wifi thing sounds normal, lots of interference in hospitals.

Comment: Thanks Gabe,  The good news is they just bought five additional units (anticipating a fix) and will let you know as soon as they arrive (fingers crossed, otherwise, ouch!!!).  The WiFi is strange as they're in an office building, and when we've run into this at larger hospitals and med schools, changing the channel has done the job (5G).  Appreciated.